# after assign JSON to a class object local functions of the class got corrupted

Tags: javascript, typescript

This is my Class object book is parent and has a child pricedeatils

```
export class Book
{
  name: String;
  auther: String;
  series: String;

  pricedeatils: Array<price>;

}
```

// this is child class

```
export class price
{
    price1: Number; 
    price2: Number;
    price3: Number;
    price4: Number;
    price5: Number;
    price6: Number;
    price7: Number; 
    public setPrice( lcol:number,lnprice:number)
    {     
            this["price"+ lcol]=  lnprice:  
    }   
}
```

im receiving through api

```
this.http.get(this.booksUrl)
  .subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

my json file looks like this

```
{
    "name": "Apple",
    "auther": "Shaik",
    "series": "Classic"

    "pricedeatils": [

                    {
                        "price1": 1, 
                        "price2": 2, 
                        "price3": 3, 
                        "price4": 4, 
                        "price5": 7, 
                        "price6": 10, 
                        "price7": 8, 
                      },
                      {
                        "price1": 11, 
                        "price2": 22, 
                        "price3": 23, 
                        "price4": 34, 
                        "price5": 37, 
                        "price6": 10, 
                        "price7": 38, 
                      }, 
                      {
                        "price1": 31, 
                        "price2": 33, 
                        "price3": 24, 
                        "price4": 34, 
                        "price5": 37, 
                        "price6": 10, 
                        "price7": 38, 
                      },


                ],
}
```

after receiving json im not able to call class local function.

```
this.Book.pricedeatils[0].setobj(1, 15)
```

getting error like this 
core.js:12301 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.Book.pricedeatils[0].setobj is not a function

Comment: functions do not deserialize from JSON. You would have to metaprogram in order to serialize and deserialize a javascript function through JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON you received from server is converted to object using `JSON.parse` method. output of JSON.parse is always an array, object, number or string (until a [reviver parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Parameters) is not used) . It is not an instance of your class `Book` or `price`.

I have also faced same problem in past, I solved it by creating a copy constructor for my classes and passing values received from server to it, as below

```
export class price
{
    constructor(source: price){
      this.price1 = source.price1;
      this.price2 = source.price2;
      this.price3 = source.price3;
      this.price4 = source.price4;
      this.price5 = source.price5;
      this.price6 = source.price6;
      this.price7 = source.price7;
    }
    price1: Number; 
    price2: Number;
    price3: Number;
    price4: Number;
    price5: Number;
    price6: Number;
    price7: Number; 
    public setPrice( lcol:number,lnprice:number)
    {     
        this["price"+ lcol]=  lnprice:  
    }
}
```

and

```
export class Book
{
    constructor(source: price){
      this.name= source.name;
      this.auther= source.auther;
      this.series= source.series;
      this.pricedeatils= source.pricedeatils && source.pricedeatils.map(a=>new price(a));
    }
  name: String;
  auther: String;
  series: String;

  pricedeatils: Array<price>;

}
```

and use it as

```
this.http.get(this.booksUrl).pipe(map(a => new Book(a))).subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is either setobj() does not exist on class price as I can only see setPrice() on it or when you get your book data form the http request, you're doing something like this.book.pricedeatils = res.pricedeatils which would mean you're overwriting your pricedetails array, an array of price objects (that contain your setobj() method) with an array of simple objects without the setobj() function:

```
{
  "price1": Number, 
  "price2": Number, 
  "price3": Number, 
  "price4": Number, 
  "price5": Number, 
  "price6": Number, 
  "price7": Number, 
  public setobj();
}
```

Becomes this:

```
{
  "price1": Number, 
  "price2": Number, 
  "price3": Number, 
  "price4": Number, 
  "price5": Number, 
  "price6": Number, 
  "price7": Number, 
}
```

If that is the case then think of using constructors.

Also, maybe you should share more code.

Comment: Dear, i put setPrice() wrongly, actually its  setobj() only. so you mean to say i have to submit with public setobj(); in json ? no other go ?